# How to prevent push notifications to app after reinstallation?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, token

Since iOS 9 application changes apns token after reinstallation of an application.
But  iOS 8 and 7 doesn't do it.

How can I distinguish next situation using iOS 8 and iOS 7?

1. User installed an app.
2. User launched app and allowed push notifications in the app. (I getted some token)
3. User logged in/registered. (I connected token with registered user).
4. User deleted the app.
5. User installed the app, launched it once and allowed push notifications. (getted the same token, )

After these actions, this unregisterd user will get notifications about some actions in his account without needs to log in.
If it were a bank/finance app, it would influence the security of registered user.

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];`
in
 `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. Then, when user logs in, register for remote notifications.

But anyway, if app is uninstalled and installed again, it will not receive push notifications until `-registerForRemoteNotifications` get called, and you must call this method ONLY after user authentication. Even if token is same as previous one, it will associated with this new user, and your server should handle that.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I've changed the order of actions. `registerForRemoteNotifications ` is called before user authentication, because it need for news and marketing staff. Do you have any suggestions for such situation?

Comment: If your notifications aren't user specific, then what's the problem?

Comment: When user is unregistered, I want to send only news/marketing staff. But if user is signed I want to send user specific information.

Comment: Then, in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method when you register for remote notifications and sending it to the server, your server should remove previously associated user from this token, and send only news/marketing staff. After user authentication, just send that token again with your login request. Now, your server knows, that this token is for newly logged in user and will associate that token with this user, and will send not only news/marketing staff but other pushes also.

Comment: Yes, there is such way of troubleshooting this issue. But this way opens space for attacks by sending request to server which will remove random token. I've just thought that there is some sequence of actions, which force device/apns to regenerate token. Or there is another more elegant way to escape possible attacks and handle this situation. Thank you very much for your help! (Probably you should add upper comment to your answer).